# Next/Prev (CTRL->/<-CTRL) keyboard shortcuts in javascript in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, paging

I have a simple ASP.NET page with paging support.
Basically just hyperlinks that look like this:

> report.aspx&page=1
>   report.aspx&page=2
>   etc

How could I implement a keyboard shortcut so I could go forward to next page and to previous page by just holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and pressing either <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>?

I have seen this functionality implemented on some discussion boards,
but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.artlebedev.com/tools/technogrette/js/arrow-navigation/

```
<link rel="prev" href="report.aspx&page=1" id="PrevLink" />
<link rel="next" href="report.aspx&page=2" id="NextLink" />

. . .

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.onkeydown = NavigateThrough;

function NavigateThrough (event)
{
  if (!document.getElementById) return;

  if (window.event) event = window.event;

  if (event.ctrlKey)
  {
    var link = null;
    switch (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : null)
    {
      case 0x25:
        link = document.getElementById ('PrevLink');
        break;
      case 0x27:
        link = document.getElementById ('NextLink');
        break;
    }

    if (link && link.href) document.location = link.href;
  }         
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does not seem to be working in IE8: keyCode is null or not an object.

Comment: Oops, apparently this line is required: if (window.event) event = window.event; I updated example from http://img.artlebedev.ru/svalka/navigate.js